# Database composite key in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, composite-primary-key

Condition is Each operator record has a unique group code and product code. It may possible that some group has same product code.

## main operator table

```
     id           integer                  PK 
     name         varchar(100)
```

## product group table

```
     code         integer                  PK
     opt_ID       integer                  PK + Ref. operator
     group        varchar(50)
```

## product table

```
     code          integer                  PK
     opt_ID        integer                  PK   
     group_ID      integer                  Ref. Group table code field   
     name          carchar(50)
```

problem is here what should I make a reference in product table either from operator table or either product table group?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  Are you saying that may be product_table entries that have the same group_ID?  or are you trying to make the {product_table.opt_ID, product_table.group_ID} tuple unique for the product_table?

Comment: Each operator has multiple groups of product with with unique id. Product is referenced to some groups which also has unique for operator not for group. i.e. each operator has unique group id and also a product id.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do requires another table.

```
main operator table
  id           integer                  PK 
  name         varchar(100)             Ref. Product table code field unique
  product_code integer
product group table
  code         integer                  PK
  group        varchar(50)
product table
  code          integer                  PK
  group_ID      integer                  Ref. Group table code field   unique
  name          carchar(50)
```

This should allow you to query operators by product or group.  Does this make sense for what you are trying to do?  If not include a use case.

edit.  this will insure a unique product/group tuple for each operator....you access operator.group through joining on the product table.

Comment: As I mentioned that each operator has unique group code as well as unique product code for only that particular operator. Here is a sample data operator(code=1, name="opt1"), group(code=1, optId=1, name="tea"), product(code=1, optId=1, groupId=1, name="hot TEA"), product(code=2, optId=1, groupId=1, name="cold TEA") now there is a new operator operator(code=2, name="opt2") group(code=1, optId=2, name="tea"), product(code=1, optId=2, groupId=1, name="hot TEA"), product(code=2, optId=2, groupId=1, name="cold TEA").

Comment: The problem you are stating is a consequence of that design.  What are the relationships?  A product HAS-A group and a group HAS-A product?  Am I following?  and then an operator HAS-A unique product and HAS-A unique group?  I will edit my answer to reflect